# Double Quotes in Hadoop Hive Query

Tags: powershell, azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am able to use Double Quotes in following query ->

```
$subscriptionName = "***"
$clusterName = "***" 
$queryString = "SELECT city FROM logs WHERE city =""New York"";"
Use-AzureHDInsightCluster $clusterName
Invoke-Hive -Query $queryString
```

But I am not able to use Quotes in following PowerShell Comamnds -

```
$subscriptionName = "***"
$storageAccountName = "***"
$containerName = "***"
$clusterName = "***"

$queryString = "SELECT city FROM logs WHERE city =""New York"";"

$hiveJobDefinition = New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition -Query $queryString

Select-AzureSubscription $subscriptionName
$hiveJob = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition $hiveJobDefinition

Wait-AzureHDInsightJob -Job $hiveJob -WaitTimeoutInSeconds 36000

Get-AzureHDInsightJobOutput -Cluster $clusterName -JobId $hiveJob.JobId -StandardOutput
```

It is giving me following error -

[image]

Please give me some information why is this sporadic behavior. Both implementations creates jobs, then why one implementation accepting double quotes and other not.

Answer (score -1):

Try a couple of alternate ways of quoting your query to see if you get any further:

**Single Quotes**

```
$queryString = 'SELECT city FROM logs WHERE city ="New York";'
```

**Backtick Escape**

```
$queryString = "SELECT city FROM logs WHERE city =`"New York`";"
```

My guess is that it is the way that `Start-AzureHDInsightJob` is interpreting the string differently.

**Update 1**

Sorry to hear the above didn't work, maybe try (single quote string):

```
$queryString = "SELECT city FROM logs WHERE city ='New York';"
```

**Update 2**

Looking at [New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn527653.aspx) you haven't specified a job name, if you don't specify a job name then the following applies:

```
The name of the Hive job being defined. If the name is not specified, 
it is "Hive: <first 100 characters of Query>" by default.
```

So your job name will contain your query, try specifying a job name to see if that helps.

Comment: Both your suggestions failed with same error mentioned in my original post.

Comment: But using single quotes in query is not my original question. I want to use Double quotes, I think you are missing my point.

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to get the second command working.  My guess is that the implementation of New-AzureHDInsightHiveJobDefinition does not cater for double quotes.  Why do you particularly need double quotes?  Did single quotes not work either?

Comment: My Data got Double quotes. My confusion was, why the two implementation in my original post differ. They should do the same work.