# Azure HDInsight parameter is incorrectly quoted

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-sql-database, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to use data from a Azure SQL database with Hadoop (HDInsight).

To get the data and execute a job, I run the following code in a C# console program:

```
        var jobClient = JobSubmissionClientFactory.Connect(creds);

        //Setup the sqoop job
        string query = "import --connect \"jdbc:sqlserver://...:1433;database=...;user=...;password=...;\" --jobname testname123 --query \"SELECT * FROM HouseDatas WHERE $CONDITIONS\" --split-by ID --target-dir asv://...@....blob.core.windows.net/Input/" + Job_ID + "/";

        var sqoopJob = new SqoopJobCreateParameters()
        {
            Command = query,
            StatusFolder = "asv://...@....blob.core.windows.net/Input/sqoop_status/" + Job_ID + "/",
        };
```

**Error message:**

```
        Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Hadoop.Client.HttpLayerException: Request failed with code: BadRequest
        Content:("error":"Passed in parameter is incorrectly quoted: \"SELECT")
        at Microsoft.WindowsAzure...
        ...
```

**Some things of note:**

- It works without --query parameter, i.e. if I simply select entire tables
- The command works if executed in Powershell
- There is no error if there are no spaces in the query (i.e. --query \"SELECT\" ), but obviously that's not very useful
- Single quotes (--query 'SELECT ... $Conditions' ) work, but the job doesn't produce any output
- Using @ and double quotes doesn't work
- The problem seems similar to [Double Quotes in Hadoop Hive Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897587/double-quotes-in-hadoop-hive-query), but the answer (specifying a job name) didn't help

**So the question: Why would spaces in the query cause this error?**

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your command as a file and point at it using -File parameter. This will avoid encoding issues.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. There were still some issues but it finally worked, but I still wonder what caused the encoding issues in the first place.